# Citing "company culture" as a reason for leaving in a company of 3

Tags: communication, resignation, startup, quitting

I've decided to leave a start-up after a few months of employment because the boss has poor interpersonal skills, is disrespectful on a daily basis, and turns simple situations into stressful events.

When I was hired on it was just me and him, now there's an assistant. Would it be confrontational to admit that I'm leaving because of company culture? I want to be honest, but I'm afraid that may come across as a personal attack.

Comment: I don't see anything different about your situation that the answers from [this question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/14921/how-much-should-i-say-in-an-exit-interview) wouldn't apply. In fact, you might say that the the general advice of not burning bridges is even MORE true in your case because of the small company size and your short tenure there.

Comment: K. Franklin, that does look like a duplicate. Can you take a look at those answers and -- if they don't answer your question -- come back here and [edit] this post to clarify?

Comment: After you've moved on, invite your present boss to a drink or Saturday lunch and have a leisurely chat. I would avoid mentioning that when emotions are running raw - talk to him later when the water is under the bridge and both of you have better perspective.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Would it be confrontational to admit that I'm leaving because of
>   company culture?

In a company of 3, it's pretty silly to talk about "company culture". It's you, your boss, and one other. "Culture" is simply too fancy of a word.

Just tell your boss that it isn't working out for you, that you aren't a good fit for the situation, and move on.

Avoid trying to blame "the company culture" and avoid specifics about your boss' failings, unless you are on very, very friendly and casual terms with him (for example, if he is also a lifelong friend). Otherwise keep it simple, keep it professional, and try not to burn any bridges.

In a larger company, the term "culture" makes sense. Company culture is formed over time, and usually driven from the top. Often, it is shaped as part of the founders' vision.

In this tiny company, it's just the personal interactions of 3 people that didn't work out. It happens.

Comment: You could argue that with two people the OP is 50% responsible for the 'culture'.