# How can I politely turn down the exit interview?

Tags: interviewing, exit-interview

I already know that there is no benefit in being honest or in giving good suggestions to improve things at the company as no change will be applied from the exit interview suggestions.

I also do not want to burn any bridges by attending the exit interview and being honest.

So what is best way to say no to attending the exit interview? I just don't want to face it.

Comment: also see https://www.forbes.com/sites/lizryan/2017/07/06/ten-reasons-to-skip-your-exit-interview/#7c4f239320e3

Answer (score 179, accepted):

If your company wants to have an exit interview, it is unlikely that you can avoid it (at least not without damaging your relationship with the company).

Go to the interview.  Feel free to politely answer questions without being brutally honest.  "I don't have any suggestions to give you", for example, can just as easily mean that you're politely declining to share suggestions that you don't expect to be implemented.

Comment: Yes, this.  Just wear your game face for the half an hour and it's over.

Comment: Thank you justin, I would love to complete exit interview in a way like you suggest.

Comment: Agree with this. Also, you really shouldn't be don't be anxious about yet another interview. On this one, there is no consequence (for you) to give any "wrong" answer.

Comment: "I decline to answer that question as I do not wish to prejudice my future relationship with the company"

Comment: @MarkBooth: Not sure if that was serious but if somebody said that to me it would make me think they had something horrendous to say that they were not saying and thus damage the future relationship with the company.

Comment: Yeah... don't even hint at anything that might be "damaging". Just be polite and non-committal. The truly diplomatic can make suggestions in a positive way, e.g. "I would have loved to have more opportunities to grow in the company" if career advancement options were few, but if it's not obvious how to do that, or you just don't want to, just stay really broad: "I've enjoyed my time here but was ready for a change" and just leave it at that.

Comment: Yeah I disagree with @MarkBooth's suggestion: it strongly implies that you have something bad to say and are just refusing to say it. Just be polite, say as little as possible, and describe everything about you leaving as being for personal/family etc reasons.

Comment: Although I intended the specific statement as a joke (a riff on 'taking the 5th'), there is no easy way to tell people there is a problem. A statement like that *could* lead to a post exit interview off-the-record chat, or it could lead to the very problems it intends to avoid. I disagree strongly that you should lie in your exit interview, just to avoid rocking the boat. We should take this to [chat] if it is going to result in an extended discussion however.

Comment: I disagree with your opening statement. It's perfectly feasible to swerve the exit interview with a little preparation.

Comment: You can simply say "I respectfully decline to answer all questions". Its like pleading the 5th (in USA) so that anything you say cannot be used against you in a court of law.

Answer (score 74):

> How can I politely turn down the exit interview?

**Don't.** Just attend the interview but remain noncommittal, control your temper and avoid saying *anything* negative. Resign yourself to wasting an hour or so regurgitating vague statements, trite phrases and meaningless pleasantries. Memorise phrases like:

- *The opportunity was too good to pass up*
- *I learned so much here but felt it was time to move on*
- *It made sense for me at this point in my career*
- *I'm excited about moving to Field X / Industry Y*

This is vastly preferable to refusing to attend. **You may be perfectly right on principle but you'll lose on politics.**<sup>1</sup>

Refer to this question for further suggestions on what to say, how to say it and what to avoid saying: 
[How much should I say in an exit interview?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/14921/how-much-should-i-say-in-an-exit-interview)

---

<sup>1 Paraphrased from [Alison Green](http://www.askamanager.org/2014/06/my-employer-heard-i-was-interviewing-and-confronted-me.html)</sup>

Comment: so you mean attend exit interview with positive answers and cool mind :). I think that is best way to avoid all other things.

Comment: I disagree, a bit. Find several specific positive things to say about your experience at the company. If you are asked what they can do to improve things, use those and talk about how great they are and how they should continue to do them. You'll avoid coming off as vague or evasive. You're not trying to fix things, you're trying to leave a good impression of yourself. And if it's that hard to come up with anything positive, yes, they will know you are being evasive but there's a good chance you'll run into that person in future job searches.

Comment: Can I just say that I respectfully decline to answer for every question they ask me ?

Comment: @catowa Not answering is it's own answer and can be taken to be a bit hostile, but it depends on how you phrase it. I'd suggest having some boiler plate answers ready like mentioned above for the typical questions. If they keep asking or say "did manager X make you want to leave" then it's fine to politely decline to enter into details. Depending on the situation you can also say things like "I've raised some of the things that factored into my decision with manager before", for example if you're leaving because a promotion was denied. Typically they'll already know that though.

Answer (score 38):

You will likely mess up relations even more by wiggling out of a social convention like an exit interview (if this is commonplace at your employer). You don't want your ex-boss, when asked for a reference of you, to think of you straight away as "the guy that wiggled out of the exit interview".

This may be the last possibility of leaving a positive impression. It's certainly worth it to bend over a little and do this right. After all, if you are willing to invest effort into getting out of the interview, you could just as well invest effort into doing a *professional and polite* interview and leave on good terms.

Prepare beforehand. Think of a couple of good things about your current employer, as well as a few minor things that could be improved. Have a professional reason for leaving, like wanting to see new ways of doing things, or working in a different environment.

Answer (score 25):

I don't like exit interviews for the same reasons, but thinking back, most of the exit interviews I've done weren't interviews at all. I don't remember anyone ever asking me why I was leaving, or asking for suggestions on improving things. They already knew why I was leaving.

Generally, you don't have to go to an exit interview if you don't want to. But, your company is likely required to do certain compliance notifications and other paperwork, and you may have to return keys and/or a badge. The best time to do that is an exit interview, so just go and get it over with.

Don't worry too much about it. If they ask you any uncomfortable questions, don't be rude or angry. Just give a short, generic response. For example, if they ask for suggestions on how to improve conditions, just say you don't have any. If they ask why you are leaving, say you got a better opportunity. Do nothing to prolong the meeting, and it should go quickly.

Comment: "... most of the exit interviews I've done weren't interviews at all." Agreed. While I've had exit interviews where they did ask questions about my departure and where I was going, most of them have just been going through paperwork and procedures related to the employment termination, such as whether I wanted COBRA health insurance coverage, verifying my address (for tax statements, etc.), turning in badges and keys, etc.

Answer (score 12):

From the employer's perspective, the exit interview is primarily about spelling out specific ongoing obligations.  For instance, this is when you'll hear fairly obvious things like "If you do need to come to the office for any reason, you need to be signed in", or polite reminders like "You are not allowed to divulge any trade secrets, even to your new employer". Normally you'll be asked to sign something specific HR needs. You may have agreed to things, such as supporting the company even after you leave in litigation, and you'll be asked to sign a reminder.

Some facts may be established, such as you leaving on your own accord, which affects unemployment benefits you may try to claim later.

Sometimes HR wants to cull information about your experiences for their benefit, but it is not in your best interest to tell the truth. I suspect HR rarely gets useful information from these in that respect.

If there is a dispute later, you're likely to be portrayed as leaving without fulfilling your obligations, which can undermine claims for compensation, etc.

You should be paid for the day, or at least the time.

Comment: ... **don't sign any paperwork** because "HR needs that", **take it with you instead**. If necessary, tell a white lie ("My uncle/partner/... is a lawyer, and will be very disappointed with me if I don't show this to him/her first. Silly, isn't it? But I sure won't risk angering him/her"). If they don't let you take the paperwork with you, chances are there are some pitfalls, or things you should at least not give them _for free_.

Answer (score 11):

Exit interviews are ridiculous and a complete waste of time. However, there really is no way to politely decline them.  Even if you are completely courteous, the very act of declining will be seen as disrespectful.

So you get to choose ...

- Go to the exit interview, smile and say the platitudes.
- Go to the exit interview, smile and speak your mind.
- Decline the interview.  Say something like "I don't have anything to add to what was discussed when I resigned" or "I am very busy preparing my desk for the next guy and don't think I can add anything else of value beyond what we have already discussed."

The consensus is that the first choice is the best one, and I concur.

If you are not willing or able to do so, I recommend not attending over attending and speaking your mind.  To bastardize an old proverb, it is better to be silent and thought a jerk than to speak up and demonstrate that you are jerk.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not a fan of exit interviews and have made some efforts in the past to avoid them. My strategy has been relatively simple;

- Do your best to book the exit interview for as late as possible, ideally within one or two days of your leaving date. This can usually be accomplished by claiming to be very busy "finishing things off" or simply begging your boss to find you activities on the days proposed by HR.
- On the day of the interview, claim to be suffering from toothache or an unspecified stomach condition and simply remove yourself from the office for a couple of hours to "go buy medicine", thus rendering the exit interview a missed event.

I appreciate that this may seem inelegant but please trust me when I say that it works and works well.

Comment: If it works well, I have to ask why you've had enough to develop the strategy? :-)

Comment: @jimm101 - I'm reasonably sure that my career history is none of your business.

Comment: This seems to be the only answer that's actually answered the question.

Comment: @DavidWallace - I particularly enjoyed the fact that there's 100+ upvotes for the one which says "*you can't*"

Comment: @Richard The question was "How can I politely turn down the exit interview" not "How can I get out of the exit interview". Your answer does not involve turning it down at all, and so doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @mikescott - mine is the only answer that doesn't seem to involve doing **exactly what he doesn't want to do.** All of the others are predicated on the (wrong) assumption that exit interviews are like death and taxes and that he should just grin and bear it.

Comment: @Richard - Thanks for suggesting options to avoid exit interview. I will keep it in mind.

Comment: While this may be effective, it's not polite. It's under-handed, and probably a less good solution than, e.g. Lilienthal's answer.

Comment: @PhilipSchiff - I stand by my earlier comment. This is that only answer that seems predicated on the idea of actually avoiding the interview rather than coming up with strategies to go and try to avoid saying anything impolitic.

Comment: @Richard I agree that your answer is more unique, but would characterize is "avoiding the exit interview without a confrontation" rather than "avoiding the exit interview politely".

Comment: @PhilipSchiff - My way is very polite indeed. You apologise for not being able to attend. Now, theoretically they could reschedule but in reality that will never happen.

Comment: No, it's not polite, for any definition of the term. Also your rude reply to @jimm101, that was only asking a question is not polite, just in case you were wondering (pretty sure you weren't, though).

Comment: @o0'. - Not really, no.

Answer (score 2):

Sharing my own experience in this particular case I can say: just focus on your final report you've made before. You're absolutely right if you don't want to shake the air with words where nobody listens to it.

Make a more detailed explanation of all the final report's' fields, and that should be fine! You may face direct questions about management, etc. - just say that "I'm not a proficient manager, I'm a specialist in <your field of expertise>, so I'm not even trying to think as a manager. That's why I can't fully answer your question". Of course if you was not a manager =) I'm an IT expert, and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I say you should attend the exit interview. Your employer is asking you for something for the last time, and by saying no, you will not give a very good last impression.

Plus, exit interviews can be very helpful for you too. Invite your coworkers to the exit interview and ask them for feedback on you. How you can improve? What do they like about you and what do they not? I recently had my first exit interview. I got very valuable feedback from my co-workers and employer.

Finally, prepare some general feedback for the company. I suggest that you neither be too blunt/straight, nor just keep praising the company. Give them some honest feedback that can help them and at the same time, don't offend them. Remember not to target anyone. Some of the points I can think are:

- I feel like we spent a lot of time in meetings. This should be reduced.
- I feel there are a few too many disturbances in the workplace; this happens all the time. This affects productivity somewhat.

This will give them a feeling that it is genuine and not lying/praising bluntly.