# Previous employer possibly spreading lies about me to prospective employers

Tags: hiring-process, unprofessional-behavior, privacy, australia, mental-health

I was working in a Centre, where I became really depressed and stressed, both due to my personal situation and also because of the workload, discrimination and inequalities. I resigned after sending a huge email explaining the reasons of my resignation. In retrospect, it was a bit harsh but I feel that the truth is always bitter and I wanted to get the burden off my chest.

After resigning, I rested for couple of weeks then started re-applying to places. Soon I realized there was something wrong: I got rejected from multiple places before even interviewing.

Then, I received an email from my former workplace, saying that, some of their Centres received an email about me describing my mental health in great detail. Also mentioned was how irregular I was when I worked there and also my issues with colleagues. The email was apparently from 'a very concerned parent', and judging from its appearance, is fake.
Only my manager knew my mental health with such detail as mentioned in the email. None of the parents can do that as they loved me a lot.

I contacted The Fair Work Commission here in Australia regarding this.
They asked me to contact the Office of the Australian Information Commissioner, who in turn replied that they cannot help.

I contacted the Union, DJMIR and many others but the answer is same.

1. **Where should I seek help from, because I feel that my whole career is ruined?**
2. **Can I prove that this email is from my former employer?**

Comment: Could you include some paragraphs here? It's very hard to read right now. Also; how did your manager know about your health in that level of detail? Was it a job requirement, or something you told him in your leaving email?

Comment: This is why the only thing you should ever say going out the door is "Thank you, it was a pleasure.  I wish you all well.  Goodbye"

Comment: First rule of life of work. Never say something that will somehow compromise you later. Basically the Miranda warning "You have the right to remain silent. Anything you say can be (_and will be_) used against you [...]"

Comment: I might suggest speaking to a lawyer in case such emails are illegal, although (1) it probably isn't illegal if it's true, (2) you may not be able to prove who sent it, (3) it sounds like the damage has already been done (but that's not to say you can't get a substantial cash settlement out of it).

Comment: Related: [How much should I say in an exit interview?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/14921)

Comment: Even if you somehow know that it is from your former employer, what exactly are you going to do next? Sue them for spreading around information that you voluntarily offered them? That is about as close an example you can get of dousing fire with gasoline (petrol). In other words, it will reduce your employment opportunities even more. Just learn the lesson from this experience and move on.

Answer (score 4):

You made your personal information public.  Now, what is being circulated is, in your words, "harsh, but just the truth".

Your email was a public display and from the looks of it, demonstrated enough instability as to warrant the treatment you are getting.

Nothing inappropriate was done on their part.

Comment: Well, an email from a very concerned parent seems wildly inappropriate (assuming it was indeed wrote by the company)

Comment: @ricardosilva no way to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't undo what you did, although this should be a harsh lesson to you on why leaving with an angry note about the workplace is a bad idea 100% of the time .

Since this person has chosen to retaliate, you have a couple of options. First, change careers. If he or she has notified other call centers that you are unstable, assume you can't find work at those and look elsewhere. If you can, get an education in a new field.

Second, try a different physical location. A new city might be just the thing. Use a non-manager at that workplace who you got along with well as your reference.

Next option is to take all this to a lawyer. It is possible they would have some advice to help you recover damages from the retaliation. See if you can find one who will give you a free evaluation of whether there is a  case to be made.

Get treatment for your mental illness (depression is a mental illness). If you have gotten treatment, the counselor can help you with ways to get back into the workplace with a history of mental illness.